# R - How to histogram multiple matrixes using qplot/ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I'm using R to read and plot data from NetCDF files (ncdf4). I've started using R only recently thus I'm very confused, I beg your pardon.

Let's say from the files I obtain N 2-D matrixes of numerical values, each with different dimensions and many NA values.

I have to histogram these values in the same plot, with bins of given width and within given limits, the same for every matrix.
For just one matrix, I can do this:

```
library(ncdf4)
library(ggplot2)

file0 <- nc_open("test.nc")
#Read a variable
prec0 <- ncvar_get(file0,"pr")
#Some settings
min_plot=0
max_plot=30
bin_width=2
xlabel="mm/day"
ylabel="PDF"
title="Precipitation"
#Get maximum of array, exclude NAs
maximum_prec0=max(prec0, na.rm=TRUE)
#Store the histogram
histo_prec0 <- hist(prec0, xlim=c(min_plot,max_plot), right=FALSE, breaks=seq(0,ceiling(maximum_prec0),by=bin_width))
#Plot the histogram densities using points instead of bars, which is what we want
qplot(histo_prec0$mids, histo_prec0$density, xlim=c(min_plot,max_plot), color=I("yellow"), xlab=xlabel, ylab=ylabel, main=title, log="y")
#If necessary, can transform matrix to vector using
#vector_prec0 <- c(prec0)
```

However it occurs to me that it would be best to use a DataFrame for plotting multiple matrixes. I'm not certain of that nor on how to do it. This would also allow for automatic legends and all the advantages that come from using dataframes with ggplot2.

What I want to achieve is something akin to this:
https://copy.com/thumbs_public/j86WLyOWRs4N1VTi/scatter_histo.jpg?size=1024

Where on Y we have the Density and on X the bins.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would extract the values from each raster and put them in a data.frame, one raster per column. I would melt this data.frame and plot the result using `color = variable`.

Comment: Your example figure suggests that you are looking for a scatter plot not a histogram. http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_point.html should help you how to get there.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: yes, that was the first thing I thought of, more or less well explained by fileunderwater in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, it is unclear what you are after (scatter plot or histogram of data with values as points?).

Here are a couple of examples using ggplot which might fit your goals (based on your last sentence: "*Where on Y we have the Density and on X the bins*"):

```
# some data 
nsample<- 200
d1<- rnorm(nsample,1,0.5)
d2<- rnorm(nsample,2,0.6)

#transformed into histogram bins and collected in a data frame
hist.d1<- hist(d1)
hist.d2<- hist(d2)
data.d1<- data.frame(hist.d1$mids, hist.d1$density, rep(1,length(hist.d1$density)))
data.d2<- data.frame(hist.d2$mids, hist.d2$density, rep(2,length(hist.d2$density)))
colnames(data.d1)<- c("bin","den","group")
colnames(data.d2)<- c("bin","den","group")
ddata<- rbind(data.d1,data.d2)
ddata$group<- factor(ddata$group)

# plot
plots<- ggplot(data=ddata, aes(x=bin, y=den, group=group)) +
     geom_point(aes(color=group)) + 
     geom_line(aes(color=group)) #optional
print(plots)
```

[image]

However, you could also produce smooth density plots (or histograms) directly in ggplot:

```
ddata2<- cbind(c(rep(1,nsample),rep(2,nsample)),c(d1,d2))
ddata2<- as.data.frame(ddata2)
colnames(ddata2)<- c("group","value")
ddata2$group<- factor(ddata2$group)

plots2<- ggplot(data=ddata2, aes(x=value, group=group)) +
     geom_density(aes(color=group))   
     # geom_histogram(aes(color=group, fill=group))  # for histogram instead
windows()
print(plots2)
```

[image]

Comment: The first one was **exactly** what I was looking for, my good sir, thank you! The only thing I don't understand is the use of that     factor(). In my case it just returns an error:    Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "group", value = integer(0)) :
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 2150

Comment: @AdrianoFantini The `factor` call is only to make my classification variable a factor (otherwise the legend in the plot is a gradual colour bar). From what you wrote I cannot say why you are getting the error. The thing you need to do is to have one column of densities, one of midpoints and one classifying the different groups ("multiple matrixes" in your question). If the classification is a character vector the `factor`call is not needed.

Comment: @AdrianoFantini Also, feel free to upvote and maybe accept the answer of you find it useful.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I don't understand the error either, but it works since I use only character vectors as classifications, so for now I'll not dig deeper. I accepted the answer but can't upvote it since this is my first time in SO and I don't have enough rep (yet!).  Thanks again.